# Solving exponential limit simply

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I was just looking at the following limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{2^{n}}}{n^{2n}}.
$$

I can guess that the limit is $\infty$, and plotting a graph of the numerator and denominator confirms my suspicion. I'm struggling for a straightforward way to show this mathematically, however, which would be rather nice. Any ideas?

I've attempted to use $\log$ however to do so I have to assume the limit exists, which in this case doesn't work. I also tried finding a suitable inequality without much luck.

Comment: Yes. Roughly, that's because  $n^n$ is $o(\text{double exponential})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No derivatives required here: just show the log tends to $\infty$. Indeed
$$\ln\frac{2^{2^n}}{n^{2n}}=2^n\ln 2-2n\ln n,$$
and $n\ln n=o(n^2)$, $\;n^2=o(2^n)$, so $n\ln n=o(2^n)$.